# Retornar resultados do banco de dados

Tags: php

Bom dia pessoal sou novo na programação estou criando um sistema de consulta e cadastro de usuários, porém não estou conseguindo retornar os itens já cadastrados

```
include_once("ConexaoBigData.php");

$nome = $_POST['Nome'];
$email = $_POST['Email'];

$sql = "insert into Funcionarios (Nome,Email) values ($nome, $email)";

 $salvar = mysqli_query($conexao,$sql);

 $linha = mysqli_affected_rows($conexao);


mysqli_close($conexao);
```

Comment: Não entendi, você não consegue retornar, isso é papo pra select, e porque você posta um Insert?

Comment: Acabei confundindo, nesse cado seria Select * from e o nome da tabela Obrigado !

Comment: Edite sua pergunta colocando o código pertinente a dificuladade

Comment: Usa qual versão do PHP? Talvez seja interessante usar PDO também https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 0):

Você está fazendo apenas o insert. Tente assim:

```
include_once("ConexaoBigData.php");

$nome = $_POST['Nome'];
$email = $_POST['Email'];

$sql = "insert into Funcionarios (Nome,Email) values ($nome, $email)";

 $salvar = mysqli_query($conexao,$sql);

 $linha = mysqli_affected_rows($conexao);

$funcionarios = mysqli_query($conexao, "select * from Funcionarios");

mysqli_close($conexao);
```

Com isso você terá populado a variável **funcionarios** com os registros existentes na tabela e poderá utilizar ela onde você quiser no seu código.